# Java split two integers from a string into double (converting time)

Tags: java, string, time

Part of an assignment I have for a beginning Java class is to take a time entered in as a string and convert it (while rounding to the nearest quarter hour) to a double and store it in an array. The part I am having difficult with is what to do with the two integers I receive from the split method of the String class. How do I make the two integers into one double to use in the array? (So it would be like hours.minutes, or 5.25)
Here is a snippet of code from a program I am working on:

```
    public static double convertClockOutTimes(String clockOut){
    double convertedTimeOut = 0;
    String time = clockOut;
    int hours;
    int minutes;
    String[]splitFields;
    splitFields = time.split(":");
    hours = Integer.parseInt(splitFields[0]);
    minutes = Integer.parseInt(splitFields[1]);
    if (minutes <= 7)
    {
        minutes = 0;
    }
    else if (minutes >= 8 || minutes <= 22)
    {
        minutes = 15;
    }
    else if (minutes >= 23 || minutes <= 37)
    {
        minutes = 30;
    }
    else if (minutes >= 31 || minutes <= 53)
    {
        minutes = 45;
    }
    else
    minutes = 0;
    hours = hours + 1;

    convertedTimeOut = //This is where I don't know what to do!!


   return convertedTimeOut;
    }
```

Comment: 1 minute is 1/60th of an hour, shouldn't that be used somewhere?

Comment: Aside from your question, thy to think of `x` that is not `x >= 8 || x<= 22` and then take a look at your if conditions.

Comment: Wow. Thanks everyone. I now see what I am doing and how to get the result I need. And yeah, my logic was messed up there. The teacher didn't tell me that in my planning document, but oh well. As you can tell I am pretty new to this. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 2):

I think the trick is to use a bit of math here.  You could always do the following:

```
double convertedTimeOut = Math.round(minutes / 15.0) * 0.25 + hours;
```

then you don't need the if-else tree to figure out the nearest quarter hour.

There are 15 minutes in a quarter hour, and a quarter hour is 0.25 hours.  Using the formula above, you are dividing the minutes into how many quarters of an hour you've got (0-4), which you then multiply by how many hours are in a quarter hour. Then add that to the hours you've got.

`Math.round` just does the rounding for you.

Comment: or if is needed _hours.minutes_ format, then: `double convertedTimeOut = Math.round(minutes / 15.0) * 0.15 + hours;`

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing what's giving you the most trouble is how to deal with the minutes. Try this:

```
double minutesAsDecimal = 0.01 * minutes;
```

So if the number of minutes was 24, you would end up with 0.24. I bet you'll know where to go from there.

Just as a side note, your if and else ifs are not doing what you think they are. But since it's homework.. Just take a closer look at your logic there.

Comment: sorry, my previous comment was directed at OP, not you.

Answer (score 0):

Your conditions should be AND not OR:

```
if(minutes >= 8 && minutes <= 22)
```

Etc, or better yet, a single statement, simply

```
minutes = ((minutes + 7) % 15) * 15;
```

which calculates the rounding using arithmetic rather than logic.